# os.open is not working whie I am trying to play music

Tags: python, operating-system, text-to-speech, pyttsx3

While  I am trying to open music from python using speech it was not working properly.
enter image description here
The images of code and the error I am facing was attached

```
    elif 'play music' in query:
    music_dir='/home/lokesh/Music/fav'
    songs=os.listdir(music_dir)
    os.open(os.path.join(music_dir,songs[0]))
```

- [image: List item]

help me to correct this

Answer (score 0):

The exception is raised by `os.open`. `os.open` method also requires `falgs` which tells the method in which mode to open the file, for example, in read mode, write mode, etc. You can read about different flags here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.O_RDONLY